# Compile 2 css files with Sass

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I want to compile two .css files each time I save my style.sass file

For example :

style.dev.css for development with these options :

```
sass_options = {:debug_info => true}
```

And style.css for production with these options :

```
sass_options = {:debug_info => false}
output_style = :compressed
line_comments = false
```

The goal is to have a firesass ready css file on my local machine and the compressed version on svn. For the time being I have to edit config.rb each time I want to commit my change on svn.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Is there any reason you're version controlling outputted css?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as **bookcasey** already mentioned, you should not store the compiled CSS in version control.

To deploy your frontend, use git hooks: [Automatically Recompile SASS upon Deployment Using Git Hooks](http://stevegrunwell.com/blog/recompile-sass-upon-deployment-using-git-hooks).

Second, the solution you suggested won't solve the nuisance of editing configuration each time. It's just instead of editing the `config.rb`, you'll have to edit your HTML to load the necessary CSS file.

But there's a handy workaround.

1) Modify your `config.rb` to make use of the `environment` flag:

```
if environment == :development
  sass_options  = {:debug_info => false}
  output_style  = :compressed
  line_comments = false
else
  sass_options  = {:debug_info => true}
end
```

2) Compile SASS with `compass compile -e development` for development environment and vanilla `compass compile` for production.

Yay!